# Is it possible to use type synonyms to hide type variables when declaring instances?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-synonyms

I have this typeclass:

```
class Monad m => Convertible m a b where
  convert :: a -> m b
```

For many pairs of types, the conversion can be done purely, without requiring a monadic effect.

Now, I know I can write a related typeclass like

```
class PureConvertible a b where
  convertPurely :: a -> b
```

and then make one a superclass of the other, and/or define instances of one in  terms of the other using `DerivingVia`.

But the question is about something different. What if I define a type synonym like

```
import Data.Kind
type PureConvertible :: Type -> Type -> Constraint
type PureConvertible a b = forall m . Monad m => Convertible m a b
```

The idea is that I could perhaps avoid mentioning `m` when defining `Convertible` instances, if my conversion doesn't require the features of any concrete monad. An attempt:

```
instance PureConvertible Int String where
  convert _ = pure undefined
```

Alas, this doesn't compile. The error is:

```
‘convert’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘PureConvertible’
```

Curiously enough, if I remove the `convert` method from the typeclass, the following compiles!

```
class Monad m => Convertible m a b where

type PureConvertible :: Type -> Type -> Constraint
type PureConvertible a b = forall m . Monad m => Convertible m a b 

instance PureConvertible Int String where
```

Is there a way to make this type synonym that hides `m` work, when there are methods in the typeclass?

I'm using GHC 9.2.4. Some language pragmas which might be useful:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
```

Comment: Yikes. Adding a default method in the class like `default convert :: b ~ String => a -> m b ; convert _ = pure "uhm.."` compiles. Not a real solution to your problem, but it's super weird, IMO. Something looks off: the fact that without the method compiles at all, despite the class name being hidden behind a type synonym, is surprising. I wonder if that was intended -- it's so inconsistent that it looks like a bug to me, especially since you can't add methods.

Comment: I though that `TypeSynonymInstances` would only allow 0) `instance C T where...` for `type T = Int`. I never knew that would allow to 1) alias `type C2 = C ; instance C2 Int where...`, 2) alias `type C3 = C Int ; instance C3 where...`, and even 3) provide the instance context (!!?!) as in you case. At least in my experience I have seen 0) many times in use, but 1,2,3) are novel to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but
I would suggest:

```
import Data.Functor.Identity

type PureConvertible = Convertible Identity

convertPurely :: PureConvertible a b => a -> b
convertPurely = runIdentity . convert
```

The amount of boilerplate is minimal, and the compiler should do a good job of optimizing the `Identity`-related fluff away.